# How to negate base -2 numbers?

Tags: java, math

I was given a Codility test lately and I was wondering how can I negate **-2 base** numbers?

For example the array `[1,0,0,1,1]` represents **9** in **base -2**:

```
-2 bases:

1,-2,4,-8,16

1 + (-8) + 16 = 9

[1,0,0,1,1]
```

Negative 9 in **base -2** is:

```
-2 bases:

1,-2,4,-8

1 + (-2) + -8 = -9

[1,1,0,1]
```

I'm in the dark regarding the question. There must be some intuitive solution for this. Do you have any hints?

Comment: Not trying to disrespect but the question is not clear to me. What do you want to achieve exactly?

Comment: Hint: Look at what you get if you add consecutive pairs of your base series.

Comment: I added clarification.

Comment: Or alternatively: start with observing how you negate `1`, `-2`, `4`, `-8`...

Comment: I don't see your point.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In base −2, a 1 at position *i* means (−2)<sup>*i*</sup>.

So, a [1,1] in positions [*i*,*i*+1] means (−2)<sup>*i*</sup> + (−2)<sup>*i*+1</sup> = (−2)<sup>*i*</sup> + (−2)(−2)<sup>*i*</sup> = (1 + −2)(−2)<sup>*i*</sup> = −(−2)<sup>*i*</sup>.

So you can negate any occurrence of a [1,0] by changing it to a [1,1], and vice versa.

Any other occurrences of 0, of course, can be left intact: −0 = 0.

So in your example, we split [1,0,0,1,1] into [{1,0}, {0}, {1,1}], negate each part to get [{1,1}, {0}, {1,0}], i.e., [1,1,0,1,0], and remove the unnecessary high 0, producing [1,1,0,1].

Comment: @ruakh, how to negate this numbers, like -23 which representation is 1,0,0,1,1,1 and I need to get 23 representation. And what about 42 which representation is 0,1,1,1,1,1,1. For 42 it's easy 1,0,1,0,1,0. But what logic should be for reverse conversion from negative -23 to 23 and for representations with even number of bits? Please expand your answer.

Comment: @ruakh, for example please show how to convert 1227. it's 11111011101 and would be 111101110101 converted. But I can't see how to get it step by step.

Comment: @ruakh, I think if we have remaining unnecessary 0 we should remove it. But if we have remaining 1 we should transform it to 1 => 11 and then an output is correct. Am I right?

Comment: @OlegAbrazhaev: Yup. Just as you can *remove* a trailing 0 (afterward) without affecting the value, you can *add* a trailing 0 (beforehand) without affecting the value. So -23 = [1,0,0,1,1,1] = [1,0,0,1,1,1,0] = [{1,0},{0},{1,1},{1,0}] ===> 23 = [{1,1},{0},{1,0},{1,1}] = [1,1,0,1,0,1,1].

Answer (score 4):

Let's try a few examples:

```
     (16 -8  4 -2  1)
 1 =   0  0  0  0  1
-1 =   0  0  0  1  1
 2 =   0  0  1  1  0
-2 =   0  0  0  1  0
 3 =   0  0  1  1  1
-3 =   0  1  1  0  1
 4 =   0  0  1  0  0
-4 =   0  1  1  0  0
 5 =   0  0  1  0  1
-5 =   0  1  1  1  1
```

We can try to define this mathematically:

Given input I(b) (where B is the bit number),

1. I = ∑(-2)<sup>b</sup>I(b)  -- definition of base -2)
2. O = -I -- what we're trying to solve for
3. O = -∑(-2)<sup>b</sup>I(b) -- substitution
4. O = ∑-(-2)<sup>b</sup>I(b) -- distribution
5. -(-2)<sup>b</sup> = (-2)<sup>b</sup> + (-2)<sup>b+1</sup>
6. O = ∑((-2)<sup>b</sup> + (-2)<sup>b+1</sup>)I(b) -- substitution
7. O = ∑((-2)<sup>b</sup>I(b) + (-2)<sup>b+1</sup>I(b)) -- substitution
8. O = ∑(-2)<sup>b</sup>I(b) + ∑(-2)<sup>b+1</sup>I(b)
9. O(b) = I(b) + I(b-1)

Now, this leaves the possibility that O(b) is 0, 1, or 2, since I(b) is always 0 or 1.

If O(b) is a 2, that is a "carry", Let's look at a few examples of carries:

```
       (16 -8  4 -2  1)   (16 -8  4 -2  1)
 1+1 =   0  0  0  0  2  =   0  0  1  1  0
-2-2 =   0  0  0  2  0  =   0  1  1  0  0
 4+4 =   0  0  2  0  0  =   1  1  0  0  0
```

for each b, starting at 0, if O(b) >= 2, subtract 2 from O(b) and increment O(b+1) and O(b+2).  Do this until you reach your maximum B.

Hopefully this explains it in enough detail.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine you have a number A. Then -A = A - 2*A 
Or -A = A + (-2)*A. Luckily you have base -2. And (-2)*A is equivalent to left shift by one digit. All you need now is just to implement A << 1 + A. Array shifting is easy. And then you need to implement binary addition with one small difference: each time you carry over a bit you need to multiply it by -1.

```
public int[] solution(int[] input)
{
    var A = new int[input.Length + 1];
    var B = new int[input.Length + 1];
    input.CopyTo(B, 1);
    input.CopyTo(A, 0);
    return GetResult(A, B).ToArray();
}

public IEnumerable<int> GetResult(int[] A, int[] B)
{
    var r = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < A.Length; i++)
    {
        var currentSum = A[i] + B[i] + r;
        r = -currentSum / 2;
        yield return currentSum % 2;
    }
}
```

Sorry, but the example is in C#